# Setting different keypress rate for individual keys?

Tags: xorg, keyboard

I'd like an especially high repeat rate and low delay on my backspace key, but a regular delay and rate on every other key. This command works, but sets it for every key:

```
xset r rate 120 30
```

Is there a way to have different settings for individual keys?

Comment: `xset r 22 r rate 120 30` should do what you're looking for but at my laptop it doesn't work. The keycode for backspace is 22 though.

Comment: That command appears to turn the backspace key on, and then set every key to have a given rate. It(and the similar 'xset -r 22 r 120 30') didn't set only the backspace key to have that rate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the answer to your question is **no, there is no way to achieve this** short of modyfying the X.org sources.

Here is an explanation why `xset` won't work; I am creating an answer because it corresponds to comments found in both the OP and the answer above.

`xset r` has several alternative ways of being called. Mutually exclusive, that is:

```
xset r 22
```

..will turn the repeating for keycode 22 (backspace) on, while `xset -r 22` will turn it off.

Alternatively, it is possible to specify keyboard rates, but **only** for **all** keys:

```
xset r rate [num1 [num2]]
```

You cannot combine the two.

As for the **08** / **22** confusion: **08** is the *ASCII* code for the ASCII *character* backspace, and **22** is the X windows *keycode* for the particular physical *key*.

Unfortunately, the two settings (rate / delay and per-key repeat on-off) are handled by two different X extensions:

- "rate/delay" is handled by the XF86Misc extension. `xset` changes the rate / delay using function `XF86MiscGetKbdSettings( display, values )`. The `values` XF86MiscKbdSettings structure contains only fields for repeat rate and delay (and two others of no importance here), and there is no way of applying it but general.
- the "per key on-off" is controlled by the XKB extension. The XKB extension allows to control selected keys, but the structure that holds information on these keys only contains a field that can take one of three values: default, no repeat, repeat.

In short, this seems to be impossible to achieve in the current X.org setup.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I'm likely going to turn repeating off for all keys, and selectively enable it for backspace/arrow keys.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
xset r 8 rate 120 30
```

The [the `xset` manpage at www.x.org](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xset.1.html) gives some help on the command. I also found [Keyboard Keys and Key Code Values](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000520.html), which is on Adobe's website but I think that the key codes should be correct.

Comment: everywhere that I have looked says that the keycode for backspace is `8`

Comment: If you enter `xev` in the terminal and then press backspace it will say that the keycode is 22.

Comment: some of the sites that I have looked at don't give the key that is assigned to 22, and others say that 22 is the `Page Down` key.  unfortunately I am not close to my Linux box to be able to test any of this.

Comment: You can use `xev` to find out what the keycodes are on your own system; press a key on your keyboard and it will give you the keycode.

Comment: I am on Windows right now

Comment: That command gives an error(presumably because it doesn't match one of the 4 forms for the 'r' flag given in the manual):

$ xset r 8 rate 120 30
xset:  unknown option rate

I suspect that xset by itself is not powerful enough to answer the question. I also think that 22 is a valid keycode for backspace, because 'xset -r 22' will turn repeating for backspace off.

Comment: this sucks I can't comment anywhere but here and I can't upvote. have you tried a different scope. it sounds to me like you are trying to set this inside of `X` can you set it more globally using  something that would be inherited by `X`?  I hope that makes sense